# Method that gets called on module deletion in Python

Tags: python, destructor, shutdown

Is there a method that I can add to my module, which will get called when destructing the class?

We have a simple class which has only static member functions and needs to clean up the database connection when unloading the module.

Was hoping there would be a `__del__` method either for modules or classes that don't have instances?

Comment: What do you mean by "module deletion"?  When do you think this happens?

Comment: we have a simple class which has only static member functions and needs to clean up the database connection when unloading the module. was hoping there would be a __del__ method either for modules or classes that don't have instances?

Comment: @Dan: Please update the question with new information; don't comment on your own question.  Also, what is the use case for unloading a module?  Why would you do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When destructing which class? I though you said module?

Your module lives until the interpreter stops. you can add something to run at that time using the "atexit" module:

```
import atexit
atexit.register(myfunction)
```

---

EDIT: Based on your comments.

Since you don't want it as a destructor, my answer above is correct. Just def another function (or static method if you wish) and register it with the atexit:

```
def close_database():
    proceed_to_close()

import atexit
atexit.register(close_database)
```

Now a quick note on your definition.

You said the class doesn't have any instances. So why make it a class? Why not define the functions in the module level instead? modules are first-class objects, cached and imported only once...

Example, instead of defining `database.py`:

```
class DataBase(object):
    @staticmethod
    def execute_some_query(query):
        code_here()
        some_code()
    @staticmethod
    def close_database():
        proceed_to_close()
import atexit ; atexit.register(DataBase.close_database)
```

and using:

```
from database import DataBase
DataBase.execute_some_query(query)
```

You could do this instead on `database.py`:

```
def execute_some_query(query):
    code_here()
    some_code()

def close_database():
    proceed_to_close()
import atexit ; atexit.register(close_database)
```

And use it like this:

```
import database
database.execute_some_query(query)
```

---

Or better yet: Use [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and avoid all this trouble of creating your own database interface.

Answer (score 1):

The class destructor method you're looking for is `__del__`. There are some nuances to when it's called, and to how exceptions and subclassing should be handled in `__del__`, so be sure to read the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

A quick note on terminology, too: in python a `module` is the file in which your code is located... a namespace, in essence. A single module can contain many classes, variables, and functions. The `__del__` method is located on the class, not on the module.

Answer (score -1):

Use the del method:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        print "constructor called."

    def __del__(self):
        print "destructor called."
```

Comment: __init__ is not the constructor. If you use __del__ it might be possible that the gc doesn't collect the object, so in general it is better to avoid __del__ if you can.

Comment: Technically, the class's __call__ is  the constructor; it calls __new__.  __init__ is an initializer.  A bunch of really subtle distinctions.

Comment: @S.Lott No, it's not. A class is the instance of it's metaclass so if you instantiate a class you call the instance of the metaclass. So you could say that `Class.__metaclass__.__call__` is the constructor. However normally you think of `Class.__new__` as the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Tested using bpython...

```
>>> import atexit
>>> class Test( object ):
...     @staticmethod
...     def __cleanup__():
...         print("cleanup")
...     atexit.register(Test.__cleanup__)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 6, in Test
NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
```

Comment: You've indented the `register` call so that it's part of the class, but the class doesn't exist yet.  Compare what you did with the various examples in the accepted answer.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't realise the class doesn't exist at this point.