# Writing a Python module that can tell when it's hit with Spyder's UMD (user module deleter)

Tags: python, import, module, reload, spyder

Spyder's UMD is usually great for me but periodically I trip myself when writing a module that I don't want to delete and reload. I know I can control the UMD via [*Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced settings > User Module Deleter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876306/spyder-umd-has-deleted-module). But I would also like to be able to mark certain modules I write as non-UMD friendly in the code of the module itself.

In a perfect world I would just write something like

```
assert_no_umd()
```

which would throw an exception if the module is hit by the UMD. It would be fine if the code was tripped by *any* reloading of the module, whether by UMD or otherwise.

Note that this is different from [Method that gets called on module deletion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944336/method-that-gets-called-on-module-deletion-in-python) because that question is about cleaning up a database connection which only needs to be done once, and therefore can be done with `atexit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) If I understand you correctly, this would be my `assert_no_umd` function:

```
import os

def assert_no_umd():
    mod = __file__
    if os.environ.get("UMD_ENABLED", "").lower() == "true":
        namelist = os.environ.get("UMD_NAMELIST", None)
        if namelist is not None:
            namelist = namelist.split(',')
            if mod not in namelist:
                 raise ValueError('UMD active!!')
```

Comment: Yes, thanks--this is what I was looking for. I had to make two changes to apply it: 1) I needed to use \_\_name__ instead of \_\_file__ and 2) I actually want to figure out if the module from which assert_no_umd is called, rather than the one where assert_no_umd is defined, is affected by the umd. So I use `mod = sys._getframe(1).f_globals["__name__"]`

Comment: Ok, glad that you've been able to make my code work for your purposes! :-)