# Python "on_destroy" class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, python-class

I am wondering if there is a way to call a method before the object is finally "destroyed" - like some sort of event.

I am using a class and a static method. Since it is not an instantiated object, I cannot use `del` and modify `__del__` on it.

Is the object garbage collected at all if not instantiated?

For example:

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
        print("Hello")

    def on_destroy(self):
        print("Object was destroyed...")


Test.say_hello()
```

What I want to achieve is that the method `on_destroy` will fire after `say_hello` since I am using a static method.

I tried using `__del__` and it is not being called.

Thansk for the help.

Comment: Why would you expect `on_destroy()` to be called anywhere in your code?  The global name `Test` still exists, and continues to reference your class...  If you are assuming the deletion of the name `Test` somehow, then detecting that would require that your class be an instance of a metaclass, that has a `__del__()` method.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944336/method-that-gets-called-on-module-deletion-in-python) seems related, might be helpful to you

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you describe the original problem you are trying to solve with this we might be able to propose a different solution.

Comment: In your exampe, you did not create any object, you have just called a class method, so it is totally normal that __del__ was not called, since there no object were created, garbage collection won't be called on  just calling class functions

Comment: class objects are not destroyed in cPython - once created they will "live forever". 
Just use a normal instance with a plain method. 

Static methods are useless but if you are using your classes as a namespace, (at which point it would make no sense trying to destroy them as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
        print("Hello")

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.on_destroy()

    def on_destroy(self):
        print("Object was destroyed...")

with Test() as t:
    t.say_hello()
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow. Will you please [edit] your question to explain how this solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's not guaranteed that the `__del__()` method will be called after the `say_hello()` method. So, if you still want the `__del__()` method to be called after the say_hello() method, you could do like below.

class Test:

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
        print("Hello")
        t = Test()
        return t
    def __del__(self):
        print("Object was destroyed...")
t = Test.say_hello()
```